# Can I install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on Intel Pentium Silver N5000 1.1 GHz, without problems?

Tags: 20.04, cpu, system-requirements, frequency, turbo-boost

**Background information:**

I intend to install Linux on a laptop with the following specs:

- CPU: Intel Pentium Silver N5000

  - Base frequency: 1.1 GHz
  - Max Turbo frequency: 2.7 GHz
  - Cores: 4 (no hyper-threading)
- RAM: 8 GB
- Graphics: Intel UHD Graphics 605

It's a cheap low-end laptop, designed for low-power use.

I usually prefer Ubuntu, but I am prepared to use a different distro that demands less resources, if Ubuntu 20.04 LTS demands too much.

System requirements for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS:

- 4 GB RAM
- Dual Core Processor (2 GHz)

**Question 1: Is my CPU to weak?**

System requirements says Dual Core Processor running on 2GHz, which indicates total throughput of 4GHz.
The CPU on my laptop is a quad core, with base frequency on 1.1 GHz, which indicates total throughput of 4.4 GHz (before relying on Turbo Boost).

At least, on paper, it would seem to me that this should suffice, if throughput alone is the measured requirement.

But of course, in real life, it is not that simple. 
I am well aware that not all sets of instructions can be parallellized and be fed into the different cores on a whim. Some programs can be executed only on a single core.

Will Ubuntu 20.04 LTS run on Intel Pentium Silver N5000?

Will the double amount of cores make up enough for less base frequency?

**Question 2: Will Turbo-mode run continuously?**

As I have written, the base CPU frequency is 1.1 GHz, while it can be boosted up to 2.7 GHz using turbo mode. Unbuntu 20.04 LTS demands at least Dual Core Processor on 2 GHz.

Will Ubuntu force my computer to **continuously** run at least 2 cores on turbo mode to satisfy the mentioned requirement on 2 GHz?
Or will it run with the base clock frequency of my CPU?

Comment: 1. ...depends. 2. no. You have a cpu?

Comment: Does this help? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes you can its work perfect
my laptop run ubuntu 20.04
CPU: Intel Pentium Siver N5000
RAM: 4 GB

Comment: I know I'm two years behind schedule when replying to this, but yes, I can. :D Apparently, Ubuntu LTS 22.04 seems to run even better (except that they chose to run Firefox as a snap. Oh snap!)

Answer (score 0):

For N5000 processor, 20.04 with 5.8 kernel works great.  Had [soft lockup issues](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1955429) with 5.13 kernel.  Don't know if newer kernels are better, though.